# Android - Text in TextView doesn't align left/vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, alignment

Ok, this is the deal:
I have a list containing an ImageView, a TextView and an IconTextView.

The TextView contains text that I want centered vertically and clinging to the left side of the TextView. But for one reason or another it doesn't work with android:gravity="center|left" nor any other of the gravity variations.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/task_item_item_layout"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/task_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_icon"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/task_item_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TODO"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_item_icontextview"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/task_item_imageview"
        android:gravity="center|left" />

    <IconTextView
        android:id="@+id/task_item_icontextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MinSDK = 14
Target and compiled SDK = 19

I've found a lot of potential answers, but non of them seem to work.
Any ideas?

**solution**

I altered the layout_height to android:layout_height="fill_parent" and added android:layout_centerVertical="true" like Apoorv said.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/task_item_textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/task_item_icontextview"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/task_item_imageview"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Works like charm!

Comment: Did you tried with gravity="center_vertical|left" ? Where the text appears in your textview ?

Comment: try android:layout_width="wrap_content" for your textView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in the `TextView`. At present you are using `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` as a result the `TextView` will probably be sticking to the top of the parent layout.

So when you give the `android:gravity="center|left"` it is being applied but you are not seeing any difference because the height of `TextView` does not change.

Also you can change to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` instead of using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Comment: Awesome! Up and running! I already tried the layout_centerVertical="true" and it worked on android 4.1, but didn't work on 4.2. I modified the fill_parent and both are looking fine at the moment! Thanks!